# Calculate output impedance using negative feedback theory

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, cmos, feedback

This is a cascode amplifier. I would like to calculate output impedance of this circuit using negative feedback theory.

I have heard that there is a negative feedback here but I don't see where is the feedback so I can apply it to calculate output impedance.

Rout = rds1 (1 + loop gain) ≈ rds1*gm2*rds2.

Hope someone could help me out.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your next step must be to draw a small signal equivalent of this circuit as that output impedance is a small signal parameter ! Also you draw "Vout" at the output but this circuit has a **current output**, so make "Vout" "Iout" and you're good.

Comment: Thanks. I already drew small signal model as above but I don't see what you meant to say now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - its rather simple. From feedback theory we know that the output impedance will be increased by the factor (1+loop gain LG). Therefore:

**r(out)=r(ds2)*(1+LG) with**

loop gain LG=(transconductance*load resistance at the source node of M2)

Hence: **LG=gm2*[r(ds1)]**.

Of course, a resistor RD which is connected at the drain of M2 must be considered in parallel to r(out).

**Explanation of the feedback effect:**

Here we have, in principle, the same situation as for common-emitter amplifiers with Re-stabilization (emitter resistor Re). This resistor provides current-controlled voltage feedback (a rising current Ic causes an increase of the emitter voltage Ve thereby reducing Vbe and counteracting the Ic increase). In the present circuit, the transistor M1 assumes the task of Re and acts as a stabilizing dynamic resistance r(ds1).

**EDIT/Comment:**
The above loop gain expression assumes IDEAL feedback conditions, which in reality hardly exists: In this case, ideal voltage feedback (and no current feedback). As a consequence, the loop gain expression contains a certain error. For an exact calculation, both voltage- and current feedback are to be found separately and combined using Middlebrooks formula.

Comment: Thank you. I see where is the feedback and how to calculate it now. However, I am a bit confused. With feedback I think you meant the input is at gate of M2 and rds1 is as degeneration resistor. But the actual input is at the gate of M1. So is there any problem with that?

Comment: anhnha, please not that you can set r(gs) to infinite; hence, the parallel combination reduces to gm2*r(ds1). More than that, the given expression for r(out) is an approximation (second-order term neglected).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But for the feedback system, we always have input and output. So what is the input of the system here? From what you describe above, I think you mean input is at the gate of transistor M2.

Comment: I think, you have shown the input and output terminals in your diagram, don`t you?

Comment: anhhna, please notice the comment I have added.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't express myself clearly. For example, the input signal is Vin at the gate of M1, then for the voltage feedback, the feed backed voltage should be subtracted from Vin. However, here the feed backed voltage is subtracted from Vb not Vin. So I am confused if Vb is the input.

Comment: anhhna, OK now I understand. Yes - it is a bit involved. As far as the gain of the whole circuit is involved (Vout/Vin) there is no feedback effect because Vout does not react back to the input Vin. However, the situation is different for the output resistance. In this case, the node at Vout must be seen as an input (for measurement as well as simulation) and the source terminal of M2 acts as an output. But this terminal is not grounded but it has a dynamic resistance r(ds1) between source and ground - and this is the cause of a feedback effect (like RE in the BJT amplifier).

Comment: Thanks. I have some questions now. As you said, the whole circuit there is no feedback from Vout to Vin but there is a local feedback loop. Is the feedback theory also applied for the case with local feedback loop? I mean Zout seen from Vout also increases if there is only local feedback? Could you give me some formal proof of this?

Comment: I see only one single feedback effect - and that is the described case (input at the node "Vout"). You may it call "local" or not. That is not important. Of course, the theory of feedback is applicable for all loops (local or not). As you can see, the given expression for r(out) uses the classical feedback formula which involves the loop gain.